# GTK 3 apps text backdrop looks wrong, on any theme

Tags: arch-linux, gtk, theme

I am having a problem with GTK 3 applications (GTK 2 apps work correctly): no matter which theme I choose, there are many places where colors are off.

E.g. in the screenshot you can see that the background color of the tab doesn't match the background color of the text within that tab.

[image]

How can I fix this? I am using Arch Linux with KDE 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved (at least when using KDE) by installing the `oxygen-gtk2` and `oxygen-gtk3` packages and setting the GTK2 and GTK3 themes accordingly. (edit: actually, any theme with both GTK2 and GTK3 versions should work; you can find many on e.g. [GNOME-Look](http://gnome-look.org))

Install the `kde-gtk-config` package from AUR to set those from within KDE's control panel. Now looks much more consistent with the rest of the environment, e.g.:

[image]