# Ubuntu 12.04, black background for some areas of GTK programs under KDE

Tags: ubuntu, kde, graphics

I use ubuntu 12.04, x86_64, kernel 3.2.0-35-generic.
I use KDE desktop. However, under KDE the GTK programs have black background in some areas.
e.g.
[image]
How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using `gedit` and `evince` (consider using the native applications for KDE, `kwrite` and `okular` respectively), which are both GTK 3.

I had [this similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58523/gtk-3-apps-text-backdrop-looks-wrong-on-any-theme) and was solved by setting GTK themes in KDE: install the `kde-config-gtk` package and set the GTK theme (e.g. the Oxygen theme - I don't have an Ubuntu here to check the package name, I think it's `oxygen-molecule`).

Comment: I don't have this problem using fedora 17 KDE (4.9.4) w/ GTK 3 apps like evince.

Comment: I have installed kde-config-gtk. And the problem is indeed caused by the GTK theme QtCurve I set. After QtCurve is changed to oxygen-gtk, the balck areas disappear.