# Gnome 3.12 - GTK Apps black areas glitch

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, intel-graphics, bugs, gtk3

This is my first question here so I hope I'm asking it the right way.
My setup is:

- ubuntu gnome 14.04
- gnome 3.12
- gtk2 (version 3.12.2) and gtk3 (version 3.12.2) installed
- integrated Intel Graphics 4400

Occasionally I experience a strange graphic behavior with some applications: click-able parts of them are completely black/transparent and assume their correct colors only if I click on them. The 2 pictures below show the before/after with GTKwave (a software I must use for a class in digital systems design).

[image: Before]
[image: After few clicks (notice the black bar with no click-able items that persists on the upper right)]
This is not the only app which shows this behavior, but it's quite annoying in this case. Also, if I resize the window the bug pops up again and I have to "repaint" the whole thing.

The only similar question I found was [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60879/ubuntu-12-04-black-background-for-some-areas-of-gtk-programs-under-kde), but it's KDE related and I'm using GNOME.

I tried to change the gnome-shell theme back to default (was using numix), but nothing happened.

Any chance I can fix this? I look forward to your suggestion because I'm a little bit stuck at the moment and don't want to run the simulations on a virtual machine.

Thanks in advance,
Andrea